# Why isn't Digikam 4.4 showing previews of RAW images?

Tags: software, raw, digikam

I'm using Digikam to organzie my photos and use the direct import from my Nikon camera. Using JPEG pictures, I can select some of them by the preview and import pictures selectively into different albums.

When I took RAW photos, it looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]

Is it possible to have Digikam to show me the RAW-internal preview pictures?

Using Version 4.4.0.

To the comments:
It is possible to see the pictures after they have been imported. So it's not a question of installed codecs.

My installed version 4.4.0 is from November 2014, but I can update to 4.6.0 from this January.

I'm using a Nikon D7000 camera.

Comment: Do you have the Nikon codec installed on your computer?

Comment: Probably a good idea to indicate what camera you have.

Comment: Seems like old problem in digikam. I am not sure if version 4.4 > 4.13, but please check this thread: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=213&t=101042 and try to update the software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to version 4.6.0 helped. Now, the preview is also in the import window :)

Thanks anyway for your support.